# Why would sacrificial ritual of virgin maidens appease the dragon of calamity?

Tags: mythical-creatures, dragons, historical-events

Set in the Han Dynasty, Emperor User6760 together with his trusted subjects would be busy preparing the grand sacrificial ceremony which is held once every 76 years, Ok cut the crap version: a dragon of extraterrestrial origin will hitch a ride on Halley Comet and come to Earth during the flyby, any encounter would end badly for human. According to the historians cum astronomers, the arrival of the inauspicious star would signify the collapse of the Dynasty and the only viable solution is to sacrifice 108 legitimate virgin maidens to help calm the angry dragon. Sadly the urban legend is true so the case is being referred to the Nine Ministers to establish facts and come up with credible explanation for the public. Alright for now dragon is fed and no longer posing any threat, what solid excuse can the Nine Ministers cook up beside offering a sincere condolences to the victims families? Importantly history must be sympathetic to Emperor User6760 period.

Comment: Does the dragon visit the capital or wherever in person? How is the sacrifice conducted. If it is simply that the dragon shows up at a public square and 108 girls are handed over, just make it open to the public, including the families of the girls

Comment: @nzaman: the dragon send a telegram using the Big Dipper to the astronomers on the ground, it can sense concentration of life force with its disproportional feelers located  around the groin region.

Comment: Which dynasty is this? Shouldn't the Amazon rainforest have a higher concentration of life force than China? Why is it Emperor User6760's problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sacrificing virgin superstition happen in ancient china especially to the river like yellow river simply because it flood and kill many people.

they refer them as the river bride by drowning them, until they get educated regarding river control like water canal, aquaduct, and stuff like that.

heck some/other kingdom or civilization even sacrifing human for building an object like tomb,bridge,even fortress or castle, just from superstition alone especially during that timeline.

also your dragon is real that mean they can destroy the empire of Han in real, either through flooding like most chinese dragon can do or burning/scorching the empire, i dont think you need any more reasonable excuse to confirm people than that.

just spread the truth to the public about the urban legend is real, even if they never see it, the fear of the unknown is enough to make some will believe it.

for the compensation to the sacrifice virgin you can reffer them as martyr,saint,hero,etc or give their family prestise to ease the family sorrow just like how some kingdom do with sacrificial ritual and try to make it as painless as possible like give them pain killer or other drug to disipate the pain. and maybe that can also make the dragon dislike the taste and never return for another meal or get overdose/drunk like most dragon get slayed in the myth, but i guess it can also the reason they come each 76 years simply because they get addicted in the first place).

or you can make a bounty to people to get a willing sacrifice in exchange of turning their family into nobility or rich etc.

for why the dragon prefer a virgin, well.....maybe simply that just the dragon fetish or preference, or maybe the dragon is a food conoisseur or exotic cuisine hunter, or it have purity that link with immortality or vitality or increase the magical or mystical ability, like the believe in china or other kingdom that day ( i forgot the name, the china have inside technique/method to prolong a person vitality/life, hint emperor Qin Shi Huang have alot of virgin concubine in his attempt to prolong his life and doing kamasutra thing).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to Li Jun's answer since I am unable to comment under his answer. Virgins are preferred because ancient civilizations do give a lot of importance on purity of the brides. So, that's why sacrifices are all virgins, you don't want to give anything lesser to avoid angering the gods, child brides are not uncommon too. There are some stories too about virgins having significantly more Yin energy than non-virgins which might explain why powerful beings desire them (to increase their powers).

As for the excuse, just explain the dragon demands a bride and the families of the sacrificed are honored by the the rest of the empire for their sacrifice (or just the fact their family are now connected to dragons). They will be given privileges and cared for by the empire as part of the perks.